Can I move to Canada and work Remotely for my USA Employer?
I am a US citizen (born here), and my wife is also. I work remotely at a US based company job, in the USA.
The company does have offices in Canada.
I would like to move to Canada for a number of years (maybe permanently if all works out).
I am in my 50s .
I think I want to maintain my US citizenship to make it easier if we decide to move back.
I do not want to ask for the job to be from the Canadian office , as that would complicate things for the company (and me if I move back or retire).
I just want to be a Canadian resident working a foreign (USA) remote job (similar to a Digital Nomad).
I know I will likely have to pay taxes in both USA and Canada.

What are my options?
What are the advantages/disadvantages of these options?
Has anyone here done this, or similar? Please let me know if you have and opinions or experience.


A lot of people have done that, but if not through employment - how do you intend to get Canadian residency?

This question is similar to: As a US citizen, can I work remotely for a US company while living in Canada?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You should check whether you need a work permit to work here. You might wan’t to apply for permanent residency later. As a US citizen you’ll be taxed in Canada and the USA (check FACTA).
